# Populating html:select after selection of another select using jQuery with struts1

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, struts-1

I'm trying to load different contents for an option after the first selection is made. I'm getting an error about nesting within a select which it is. 
Here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
    jQuery("#stageCodeDropdown").change(function () {
      var val = jQuery("#stageCodeDropdown").val();
        if (val == 2) {
               jQuery("#ltyCodeDropdown").html("<iforisinet:decodeoptions type="<%=CodeDecodesTypes.COMMUNICATION_TYPES%>" param1="<%=LetterBusinessAreas.PRE_APPROVAL %>" />     ");
           } else if (val == 3) {
               jQuery("#ltyCodeDropdown").html("<iforisinet:decodeoptions type="<%=CodeDecodesTypes.COMMUNICATION_TYPES%>" param1="<%=LetterBusinessAreas.FIRST_GRANT %>" />      ");

        } else if (val == 4) {
               jQuery("#ltyCodeDropdown").html("<iforisinet:decodeoptions type="<%=CodeDecodesTypes.COMMUNICATION_TYPES%>" param1="<%=LetterBusinessAreas.SECOND_GRANT %>" />     ");

        }

    });
</script>
```

The html:

```
<label>Stage</label>
    <iforisinet:select property="stageCode"includeBlank="true"styleId="stageCodeDropdown" >
        <iforisinet:decodeoptions type="<%=CodeDecodesTypes.STAGES_DOC_UPLOAD%>" />
    </iforisinet:select> <br>

<label>Document Type</label>
    <iforisinet:select property="ltyCode" includeBlank="true" styleId="ltyCodeDropdown1" >
        <iforisinet:decodeoptions type="<%=CodeDecodesTypes.COMMUNICATION_TYPES%>" param0="<%=schemeType %>" param1="<%=LetterBusinessAreas.PRE_APPROVAL %>" />  
    </iforisinet:select>
```

And the error I'm getting in the log :

ERROR InsertTag$InsertHandler::doEndTag - ServletException in '/WEB-INF/jsp/pages/fileupload/fileupload.jsp': OptionsCollection tag must be nested in a Select tag
javax.servlet.ServletException: OptionsCollection tag must be nested in a Select tag

Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: This is messed up on several levels. 1) JSP tags and scriptlets are evaluated on the server, not the client. 2) If you're going to render HTML on the server, then use that rendering in JS, it must be escaped to form valid JS. 3) So you're rendering a `decodeoptions` outside of a `select` tag because... you're rendering it outside a `select` tag in your JS function. I'd take a step back and reconsider how you're approaching this.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all this being honest, I've been stepping back the last 3 hours trying multiple ways to do this, could you point me in some direction please? Thanks

Comment: Just a bit of info: if i take out the jQuery this works perfectly, accept obviously the values in the second drop down will never vary